# How to output a variable after each loop?

Tags: php, loops

Before writing this I did some research.
This is my first-ever code I did in PHP.
I did use `<php include 'vars.php'; >` but that was just a copy paste from google.

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    ${'game' . $x} = $x;
    $game1 = "GTA5";
    $game2 = "Dirt3";
    $game3 = "Skyrim";
    echo "<th>".$game."</th>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I want to make a loop, where the variable changes on each loop and outputs a preset name or text. What I was hoping will happen here is, that after each loop the `$x` will output "game1" "game2" "game3" etc, and because I've already preset the variables.

```
$game1 = "GTA5";
$game2 = "Dirt3";
$game3 = "Skyrim";
```

I thought that the `<th>` inner will change to `"GTA5"` `"Dirt3"` `"Skyrim"`.

Why do I need this? I have created a Table and this is a part that I want to loop.

```
<th><div class='text'>GTA5</div><div class='grid'><div onclick='()' class="res">1080p ></div><div onclick='()' class="res">1440p ></div><div onclick='()' class="res">4K ></div></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>1080p</span></div><div onclick='()' class="btn">></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>min FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>max FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>used Vram</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>1440p</span></div><div onclick='()' class="btn">></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>min FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>max FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>used Vram</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>4k</span></div><div onclick='()' class="btn">></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>min FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>max FPS</span></div></th>
<th><div class="text"><p>GTA5</p><span>used Vram</span></div></th>
```

I need to loop this 13 times and on each loop, the name `"GTA5"` needs to change.
The first tiny code was just a "try" for the bigger thing.

Comment: I'd do `$games = array("GTA5", "Dirt3, "Skyrim"); ... echo $games[$x-1];` or the like. Much simpler, much more flexible. [Official documentation here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having $game1, $game2, $game3 etc, turn the variable $game into an array with the list of games inside.

```
<?php

$game = array("GAME1","GAME2","GAME3","ETC");
$screen = array("4K","1080p","720p","480p");

echo '<table>';
$i=0;

while($i <4){

echo '<th><div class="text"><p>'.$game[$i].'</p><span>'.$screen[$i].'</span></div><div onclick="()" class="btn"></div></th>';
echo '<th><div class="text"><p>'.$game[$i].'</p><span>min FPS</span></div></th>';
echo '<th><div class="text"><p>'.$game[$i].'</p><span>max FPS</span></div></th>';
$i++;
}
echo '<table>';
```

Comment: If my answer helped you with what you wanted please mark it at as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much! I used also foreach $game AS $gamename :D The code went from about 270lines (21400 chars) to 61lines (2500 chars) and it's so easy to add new "games" to it :D Just adding 1 Value and bam.. rest does itself :D

Comment: Your welcome :), you can also add min and max FPS as arrays too, so then each array will be like 

1: GAME 1, 4k , Min FPS = 20, Max FPS = 30

2: GAME 1, 1080p , Min FPS = 30, Max FPS = 45

Comment: I did all this already :) http://ue4faq.com This is just a test. I want now to add  ID's to elements to make a show hide, but not really any idea how to do it.

Comment: you can use array_search function like this:
array_search("GAME1",$game) which will give you a return of value
 or use it like this: array_search("GAME1",$game,true); which will give you the return of the key

Comment: Another idea would be to append to the class or ID of each div. so instead of having class="text"  .. it would come out as (PSEUDO CODE) class="text $gamename $res $counter ". Just a thought.

Comment: I did add a class called "mmu1" "mmu2" "mmu3" etc to all of the things that need to be switched. I also created an array for it. I have an array that has all of the "mmu1" "mmu2" etc values. Is there a way where i can set a param to each of the buttons like "myFunction(mmu1)" etc to make it toggle the mmu1 class etc? I can easily add to each of the functions. Or should i ceate a new Question for it ?

Comment: Create a new question and add this as a link to it. Also add what you've tried so we can point you in the right direction